# Capture search term?

Tags: search

Is there a function that captures search parameters? Specifically I just need the search term as a variable to compare against certain node taxonomies to add a custom filter on the search template.

I want to capture the search term without going through any Solr API. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'capture'? Do you mean getting hold of any search terms used when you're on a search results page?

Comment: yes, I mean being able to say $this_search_term = 'search term'

Answer (score 1):

Typically searching with the default search box results in a url that looks like this:

```
/search/node/[search term]
```

So you can capture that search term (in your custom module presumably) with a line like this:

```
$path = explode('/', $_GET['q'], 3);

// Make sure the path you got has three components and begins with 'search'
if(count($path) == 3 && $path[0]=="search") {
   // Get component #3 (index starts at 0)
   drupal_set_message("Here are my search terms: " . $path[2]);
}
```

Comment: Hm, when I dpm($_GET['q']) the result is 'search404'. The search is producing zero results but I still need the search query.